# PHPUnit expect call with one parameter - describe the parameter in more detail

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following phpunit mock:

```
    $this->httpClient->expects($this->at(1))->method('send')
        ->with($this->isInstanceOf(RequestInterface::class))
        ->willReturn($responseMock);
```

So the parameter for the "send" method that is being checked by the "with" function call will have to be an instance of RequestInterface. However I need to check this parameter in more detail:

- It needs to be an object that is instance of RequestInterface
- The "url" property of the object needs to have a certain value (say "https://some-domain.com")
- And the Method of the Object must be 'GET'

How might I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHPUnit's [callback constraint](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) to add custom logic to your assertions, e.g.

```
$this->httpClient
    ->expects($this->at(1))->method('send')
    ->with($this->callback(function (RequestInterface $request) {
        $this->assertSame('https://some-domain.com', $request->getUri());
        $this->assertSame('GET', $request->getMethod());

        return true;
    }))
    ->willReturn($responseMock);
```

The callback should return true if the passed object should be considered valid, but you can also make use of native assertions (`assertSame`, etc) within it - any exceptions thrown by these will bubble up to the test itself. The `instanceof` check here is taken care of by the type-hint on the callback, since a `TypeError` will be raised if it doesn't match. You could also leave out the type-hint and run `assertInstanceOf` manually if you prefer.

(Note: I've assumed you're using the [PSR-7 RequestInterface](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/RequestInterface.php) here - obviously the method names in the callback will need changing if not.)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! The Request was PSR-7 compliant, so it fits neatly.